# Не проходит авторизация php. Пробовал сделать по логину, то все проходит, а по паролю нет

Tags: php

```
<?php
    $connect=mysql_connect('localhost','root', '') or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db(regist);
    if(isset($_POST['enter'])){
        $logn=$_POST['login'];
        $password=$_POST['password'];
        $query=mysql_query("SELECT `password` FROM  `reg` WHERE  `login` = '$login'");
        $user_data=mysql_fetch_array($query);
        if(empty($_POST["password"])){
            echo "Пароль не введен";
        }
        if($user_data === md5($password)) {
            echo "OK";
            $an=true;
        }else{echo ("Неверный логин или пароль");}
    }
?>

<div class="authorization">
                <input  type="text" name="login" placeholder="Логин" required/>
                <input  type="password" name="password" placeholder="Пароль" required/>
                <input  type="submit" name="enter" value="Войти" />
            </div>
```

**Обновление**

Вот что выдает. `bool(false)`. Как я понял, то мне выдает пустой запрос? Подставил

```
$query=mysql_query("SELECT `login` FROM  `reg` WHERE  `login` = '$login'"); 
if($user_data === $login) {
        echo "OK";
        $an=true;
}
```

И все нормально проходит. А по паролю не получается.

Comment: $user_data['password'] == md5($password)?

Comment: пробовал, не получается

Comment: Забудьте вы уже про mysql_* функции, используйте PDO и бинды. Автор, у вас в запросе дыра в виде sql инъекции, а ведь ваши клиенты будут доверять вам свои персональные данные.

Comment: Знаю, что дыра есть. Я пишу сайт, чтобы изучить сам механизм.

Comment: var_dump($user_data); Походу $user_data - массив

Answer (score 1):

Разобрался. Было 2 проблемы. Опечатался и в бд было ограничение по символам. Спасибо всем, кто старался помочь.